# Managing data in android cache?

Tags: android, caching

I'm trying to finish the 'backbone' of my app in the next 3 weeks, however, one of the few obstacles I stutter at is saving data. I've had a look at saving data internally, but there is limited tutorials from what I can find of reading and writing multiple lines to files in the apps cache directory.

Basically what I'm trying to do is save the values stored inside a fragment. This fragment resets all its values when the user clicks a button and changes text to match a page number. (A number of duplicates that contain various values.) I would do multiple fragments, however, thought it would be beneficial to use just one fragment to minimize storage space needed.

I've only got round to writing to the files, and created two methods to manage this which are then called on the click of a button. One creates these files and the other writes to them. Unfortunately I'm inexperienced using adb and could only find that the files are created, but don't know if they are being correctly written to. Is there any chance someone could review this and possibly assist with re-reading the files? Help is much appreciated.

**The two methods (Warning: A great number of lines ahead):**

```
public void createEmptyFiles() {
    try {
        outputTempExerciseFileE1 = File.createTempFile("temp_exercise_1",
                ".txt", outputTempExerciseDir);
        outputTempExerciseFileE2 = File.createTempFile("temp_exercise_2",
                ".txt", outputTempExerciseDir);
        outputTempExerciseFileE3 = File.createTempFile("temp_exercise_3",
                ".txt", outputTempExerciseDir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.w("rscReporter", "Encountered an error when creating empty files!");
    }
}

public void writeTemporaryFiles() {
    try {
        if (counterAnotherExercise == 1) {
            writerTemp = new FileWriter(outputTempExerciseFileE1);
            writerTemp
                    .write(editTextExerciseName.getText().toString() + "\n"
                            + counterNoSets + "\n" + counterRepsPerSet
                            + "\n" + counterMeanRepTime + "\n"
                            + counterMeanRepTimeRefined + "\n"
                            + counterSetInterval);
            writerTemp.close();
        } else if (counterAnotherExercise == 2) {
            writerTemp = new FileWriter(outputTempExerciseFileE2);
            writerTemp
                    .write(editTextExerciseName.getText().toString() + "\n"
                            + counterNoSets + "\n" + counterRepsPerSet
                            + "\n" + counterMeanRepTime + "\n"
                            + counterMeanRepTimeRefined + "\n"
                            + counterSetInterval);
            writerTemp.close();
        } else if (counterAnotherExercise == 3) {
            writerTemp = new FileWriter(outputTempExerciseFileE3);
            writerTemp
                    .write(editTextExerciseName.getText().toString() + "\n"
                            + counterNoSets + "\n" + counterRepsPerSet
                            + "\n" + counterMeanRepTime + "\n"
                            + counterMeanRepTimeRefined + "\n"
                            + counterSetInterval);
            writerTemp.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Any of the text files should look like:**

```
editTextExerciseName
counterNoSets
counterRepsPerSet
counterMeanRepTime
counterMeanRepTimeRefined
counterSetInterval
```

**Where the two methods are called:**

```
    // In a switch statement as there are around 15 buttons
    case R.id.button_another_exercise_foreground:
        // Increases page number in fragment
        counterAnotherExercise++;
        // This then checks the page number and changes text
        checkPageNo();
        // Writing to files is called, files were created in onCreateView()
        writeTemporaryFiles();
        // Resets all the counters, giving the imitation it is a completely new fragment
        counterReset();
        // default array exercise is then set to the page number which is then displayed as title
        // For example: Exercise 1, Exercise 2, Exercise 3...
        textViewExerciseTitle.setText(defaultArrayExercise);
        break;
```

I only know the basics of Java and Android, for myself this is ambitious, however, you gotta learn somewhere! Additional suggestion for saving values are welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need files as you are only writing and then reading a handful of fixed data. Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context)) like this:

to write:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivity.this).edit().putString("editTextExerciseName", "my exercise").commit();
```

to read:|

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivity.this).getString("editTextExerciseName");
```

Comment: Would I use these in MainActivity and retrieve variables from the fragments? Just because I'm getting an error at 'YourActivity'. Meanwhile I am looking into shared preferences, thanks!